# C++ help to understand syntax of low level code

Tags: c++, winapi, syntax

I was reading some code and found really hard to understand this:

> **extern "C" NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI ObReferenceObjectByName**

Here some real code:

```
extern "C" NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI ObReferenceObjectByName(
            PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName,
            ULONG Attributes,
            PACCESS_STATE AccessState,
            ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
            POBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,
            KPROCESSOR_MODE AccessMode,
            PVOID ParseContext OPTIONAL,
            PVOID * Object
        );
```

after searching for a while I figured out that the **extern "C"** is an instruction for the compiler,
which resolves functions names like in C, and this three **NTSYSAPI, NTSTATUS, NTAPI** belong to winwdows kernel API, but I don't understand how exactly this syntax works, because it looks like there's 3 return type which make no sense, so are they some kind of preprocessor annotations like in java? or maybe (SAL) The Microsoft Source Code Annotation Language.

with this said, here is the question, **Is it this syntax is part of standart c++ lenguage or just some kind of extra functionality added by microsowft in the to compiler and how should it be readed?** Thanks

Comment: They are macros. A decent IDE will take you to their definitions.

Comment: yeahh,I just tried it with VS, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one return type, `NTSTATUS`, which is an enumeration. The others are modifiers on the function call, for example `NTAPI` resolves to `__stdcall`, which modifies how the function is called by the compiler, and `NTSYSAPI` resolves to `declspec(dllimport)`, which marks the function as a library import.

Also this has nothing to do with SAL.

Comment: okay, but still how come this syntax is compiling, is it like I said before ,some extra decorators added in the compiler?

Comment: @Jhonycash Yes, via preprocessor `#define` statements in the Windows SDK headers that are processed earlier in the compilation process. `NTSYSAPI` is defined in `ntdef.h` (`#if !defined(_NTSYSTEM_) #define NTSYSAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT #else #define NTSYSAPI DECLSPEC_EXPORT #endif`), as well as in `winnt.h` (`#if !defined(_NTSYSTEM_) #define NTSYSAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT ... #else #define NTSYSAPI ... #endif`). `NTAPI` is defined in `winnt.h` (`#if (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED) #define NTAPI __stdcall
#else ... #define NTAPI #endif`)

Comment: Ohh alright I see now, besides I kept searching for more informations and all this macros  "declspec", "__stdcall", are c++ intern functions and can be added at the left side like function decorators, thanks a lot!